How to use the -d parameter to enter a path with parentheses when the windows terminal starts
wt -d G:\[Week]\
Executing it this way will only take you to the directory below.
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

Also right-clicking a directory called [Week] and selecting "Open in Terminal" brings you to the command line, but in the powershell directory as you posted. Without the [] this doesn't happen. This feels like a bug or a security feature.
